# R - set group_by / summarize values as new column on group members

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tibble

How do I apply / set the result of a `group_by` + `summarize` as a new variable for all observations of that group?

Let's say I have a `tibble` like follows:

```
foo <- tribble(
    ~x, ~y, 
     1, 1, 
     1, 5, 
     1, 2,  
     2, 1, 
     2, 7, 
     2, 3)
```

`x` signifying the group, `y` a variable.
I know I can get the `max`-y of each group via `foo %>% group_by(x) %>% summarize(max(y))`.

How do I set this result now though as a new column for the entire group?
I.e. resulting in

```
~x, ~y, ~max-y
 1,  1,  5
 1,  5,  5
 1,  2,  5
 2,  1,  7
 2,  7,  7
 2,  3,  7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can simply use mutate after group by and specify the function:

```
foo %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  mutate(max_y = max(y))
#output:
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   x [2]
      x     y max_y
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     5
2     1     5     5
3     1     2     5
4     2     1     7
5     2     7     7
6     2     3     7
```

Comment: Couldn't see the forest for the trees, thank you!